# AccessControlException when invoking method using JAAS

Tags: java, access-control, jaas, accesscontrolexception

I have built a client/server app with JAAS. The login seems to work OK, as logins are successful. It is when trying to grant permissions to specific methods that the `AccessController` starts casting `AccessControlException`.

```
 java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("myPackage.CustomPermission" "someMethod")
```

The permission-class:

```
public class CustomPermission extends BasicPermission {

    public CustomPermission(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public CustomPermission(String name, String method) {
        super(name, method);
    }
}
```

I have a custom Principal-class as well:

```
public class CustomPrincipal implements Principal {
    private String name;

    public CustomPrincipal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

When logging in, a user provides a username and a password. In the DB the usernames and passwords have a "user level" associated to them. These user levels are used as principal-names, added to the `Subject` created when logging in. I add it when handling the `commit`-method in the `LoginModule`:

```
public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
    if(status == ConfigValues.NOT || subject == null)
        return false;

    principal = new CustomPrincipal(userlvl);

    if(subject.getPrincipals().add(principal)) {

        username = null;
        password = null;

        status = ConfigValues.COMMIT;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

For the sake of it, this is how I instantiate the login-procedure:

```
LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("MyLoginModule", new RemoteCallbackHandler(username, password));

lc.login();

new ServerImpl(lc.getSubject());
```

The `Subject` is then used in a "proxy" server implementation to check for permissions, like this (`user = lc.getSubject`):

```
public String someMethod() throws RemoteException, PrivilegedActionException {
    return Subject.doAs(user, new PrivilegedExceptionAction<String>() {
        @Override
        public String run() throws PrivilegedActionException, RemoteException, ServerNotActiveException {
            AccessController.checkPermission(new CustomPermission("someMethod"));
            return realServerImplObj.someMethod();
        }
    });
}
```

The .policy-file:

```
grant codeBase "file:./bin/-" Principal myPackage.CustomPrincipal "user" {
    permission myPackage.CustomPermission "someMethod";
};
```

The "user" is of course one of the user levels you could login with.

I've tried to add some extra grants, like:

```
grant codeBase "file:./bin/-" {
    permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "createLoginContext.MyLoginModule";
    permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "doAs";
};
```

I  have a config for the LoginModule as well:

```
MyLoginModule {
    myPackage.MyLoginModule required debug=true;
};
```

I set the properties *before* all this, of course: *edit: the files are located in the root of the project*

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "file:./MyConfig.config");
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:./MyPolicy.policy");
```

The server is run with the `-Djava.security.manager` argument. The client does *not* use any arguments, nor any config- or policy-files.

I've tried to remove the codeBase to see if my path was wrong. If I add `permissions java.util.AllPermissions`, then all is fine (but... of course it's not fine, as this is definitely not as intended). What am doing wrong here? I guess it's a combination of the Principal-, Permission, .policiy- and LoginModule-implementation.

**EDIT**
It is when the `AccessController.checkPermissions(...)` is called in the "proxy" server implementation that the exception is thrown.

**EDIT 2**
I have tried with the following edit of the code:

```
return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<String>() {
    @Override
    public String run() throws PrivilegedActionException, RemoteException, ServerNotActiveException {
        //AccessController.checkPermission(new CustomPermission("someMethod"));
        return realServerImplObj.someMethod();
    }
});
```

Note that I've changed `Subject.doAs(user, new Privile....` to `AccessController.doPrivileged(new Privilege`.
The `user` is no longer parsed in the parameter, and we use the static method `AccessController.doPrivileged`, rather than the `Subject.doAs`.
Another note:
`//AccessController.checkPermission(new CustomPer...`
has been commented.

But now everyone can invoke any method, as we actually never check for permissions. **It is as if the AccessController never is aware of the permissions granted in the .policy-file.**

**EDIT 3**
It seemed to be an issue with the implementation of the Principal that was the issue.

Just for clarification, these are the edits that have been made:

```
@Override
public String someMethod() throws PrivilegedActionException {
    return Subject.doAsPrivileged(user, new PrivilegedExceptionAction<String>() {
        @Override
        public String run() throws PrivilegedActionException, RemoteException, ServerNotActiveException {
            AccessController.checkPermission(new CustomPermission("someMethod"));
            return realServerImplObj.someMethod();
        }
    }, null);
}
```

Difference is the `return Subject.doAsPrivileged(user, ... , null);`. Note the null at the end as well.

Implemented two methods in the `CustomPrincipal`-class, `#equals(Object)` and `#hashCode()`. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/SamplePrincipal.java) for a general-purpose example of both methods, and a sample `Principal` implementation in general.

Also added (even though it seems to be running without, actually) the following the the .policy-file

```
grant codeBase "file:./bin/-" {
    permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "createLoginContext.MyLoginModule";
    permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "doAs";
    permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "doAsPrivileged";
};
```

`permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "doAsPrivileged";` is the newly added entry.

Comment: Try granting `AuthPermission("doAsPrivileged")` to "file:./bin/-" and substituting `Subject.doAs` for `Subject.doAsPrivileged(..., null)`.

Comment: *...substituting `Subject.doAsPrivileged(...,null)` for `Subject.doAs`* is what I actually meant above.

Comment: @Uux It turns into an ambiguous type error for Subject.

`doAsPrivileged`  also takes 3 parameters: `(Subject, PrivilegedAction<T>, AccessControlContext)`. I've tried by given doAsPrivileged the parameters `(user, null, AccessController.getContext)`.

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve by doing this (ignoring my previous notes; let's say it was possible). Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Uux I just had a breakthrough, I've updated my question in OP.

Comment: I removed my edit, I got ahead of myself. It didn't work as intended. :-)

Comment: Sorry for being vague; I was referring to `Subject#doAsPrivileged(yourUser, yourAction, null)`. The `null AccessControlContext` is what matters here, for it will effectively adjust the `Permission`s of the stack frame *following* the `doAsPrivileged` invocation to *exactly* those having been granted to `yourUser`. Note that whether this will result in privilege *escalation* or *reduction* depends solely on what `yourUser` has been granted at the `Policy` level.

Comment: Yes, after reading your comment a few times, I actually did test with a null-object in the AccessControlContext parameter. With no luck, though. :-(

Comment: Next guess: Have your `Principal` implement `#hashCode()` and `#equals(Object)`.

Comment: It worked. Dangit, of course. I guess it uses the equals-method to do a assessment between the new Permission we create in the checkPermission-parameter, and the created in the .policy-file?

Now I just have a very, very strange glitch. Some user have more permission than they should. I'll try work on it. If you make an answer, I'll set it as the correct one. :-)

Comment: Well, no, my guess is that it's an implementation detail of the default `Policy` (`sun.security.provider.PolicyFile`) which, in the absense of `Principal#equals` is unable to verify that the *active* `Principal` is "equivalent" to the one in its `grant` statements. Can you explain what you mean by "more permissions"? What would their expected permission set be? What are they actually being granted?

Comment: Of course, I don't know why I'm talking about the permissions as it is obviously the principals that were fixed, hehe.

Comment: And never mind about the issue wiith permissions. Was a minor brainfart by me - during the edit of the code, some of the methods had had the `AccessController.checkPermission` stripped. Basically no permission checks were done. ;-)
Can you make an answer? I'll upvote + set it as correct answer, as it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `Subject#doAs` vs `Subject#doAsPrivileged`

The default authorization algorithm employed by the `AccessController` is based on `Permission` *intersection*: If *all* of an `AccessControlContext`'s `ProtectionDomain`s, potentially *[combined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/SubjectDomainCombiner.html#combine-java.security.ProtectionDomain:A-java.security.ProtectionDomain:A-)* with a `Subject`'s `Principal`s, have, statically and/or as per the `Policy` in effect, the `Permission` being checked, the evaluation succeeds; otherwise it fails.

`Subject#doAs` does not work in your case because your `Permission` is `grant`ed to the combination of your `ProtectionDomain` and your `Principal`, but not to the domain itself. Specifically, at the time of the `AccessController#checkPermission(customPermission)` invocation, the effective `AccessControlContext` included following relevant (as far as `Permission` evaluation is concerned) frames:

```
Frame # | ProtectionDomain          | Permissions
--------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------
 2      | "file:./bin/"             | { CustomPermission("someMethod"),
        | + CustomPrincipal("user") |   permissions statically assigned by default
        |                           |   by the ClassLoader }
--------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------
 1      | "file:./bin/"             | { AuthPermission(
        |                           |   "createLoginContext.MyLoginModule"),
        |                           |   AuthPermission("doAs"), default as above }
--------+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------
```

The intersection of those frames' permissions does of course not include the desired `CustomPermission`.

`Subject#doAsPrivileged`, when given a `null AccessControlContext`, on the other hand, does the trick, because it "trims" the effective context's stack to its top-most frame, i.e., the one from which `doAsPrivileged` gets invoked. What actually happens is that the `null` (*blank*) context gets treated by the `AccessController` *as if* it were a context whose permission evaluation yields `AllPermission`; in other words:

`AllPermission` ⋂ *permissions<sub>frame<sub>2</sub></sub>* = { `CustomPermission("someMethod")`, default ones } ,

which is (save for the minimal set of seemingly extraneous statically-assigned `Permnission`s) the desired outcome.

Of course, in cases where such potentially arbitrary privilege escalation is undesired, a custom context, whose encapsulated domains' permissions express the *maximum* set of privileges you are *willing* to grant (to e.g. some `Subject`), can be passed to `doAsPrivileged` instead of the `null` one.

#### Why is the `Principal` implementation forced to override `equals` and `hashCode`?

The following stack trace snippet illustrates why:

```
at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1329)
at com.foo.bar.PrincipalImpl.equals(PrincipalImpl.java:53)
at javax.security.auth.Subject$SecureSet.contains(Subject.java:1201)
at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.contains(Collections.java:2021)
at java.security.Principal.implies(Principal.java:92)
at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.addPermissions(PolicyFile.java:1374)
at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.getPermissions(PolicyFile.java:1228)
at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.getPermissions(PolicyFile.java:1191)
at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.getPermissions(PolicyFile.java:1132)
at sun.security.provider.PolicyFile.implies(PolicyFile.java:1086)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain.implies(ProtectionDomain.java:281)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:450)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
...
```

---

Further reading:

- [Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)
- [Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE - §9 - Access Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#9)
- [Troubleshooting Security](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. :-)